# How to use post method in AngularJS

Tags: angular, angular-http

I am fairly new to the Angular world, and i got some issues on using http post method. Please help me with this, thank you!

To make my code look easier, I cut out the irrelevant stuff.
Background: I use express to make a localhost:8080, and when data is posted to said host, the console will log 'catching data'. I use 'Postman' to test this host, and it does work. When I try to use the post method in my Angular code, it doesn't give any response in the console.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http, Response, Request, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {User} from './user';
import {UserService} from './user.service';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Component({

    selector: 'my-app',
    template:
    `
      ....
      <button type= "button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
      (click)= "addUser()">Login</button>
      ....

   `
})

export class AppComponent{
  user: User= {
    UserId: "",
    Password:""
  };

constructor(private userservice: UserService, private http: Http){};
hostUrl:string = "http://localhost:8080/SignIn";

addUser(){
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
let body:string = JSON.stringify( {"UserId":"Jay","Password":"asfjghj123f"} ); 

this.http.post(this.hostUrl, body, options)
                     .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                     .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

console.log('posting data...');
}   
}
```

Here is my nodejs code for localhost8080

```
'use strict';

var express= require('express');
var app = express();
var signService = require('./signService.js');
var sessionRepo = require('./sessionRepo.js');

var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({    
  extended: false
}));

app.post('/SignIn', function(req, res){
    console.log('catching data');
    res.send('hello');
});
```

Also, I am really confused on the use of 'Observable'. I see the sample code in the official tutorial, they use Observable on the post method. Why do we return things on post method, don't we just directly post things there and the only thing we got back is the status of such request?

Source Code:

```
  addHero (name: string): Observable<Hero> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.heroesUrl, { name }, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html;

Comment: sorry, on the nodejs part, I forgot to add method .listen('8080', function(){ console.log('listening to port 8080'); })

Comment: you can edit your own question for that, no need to add it here in comments

Comment: also, what does map() do? I know in JavaScript, map is doing things for an array, but i have no idea what it does here.

Comment: If it hadn't so many redunant newlines it wouldn't be so long and you wouldn't have to apologize ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Haha thanks

Comment: what do you mean by 'it doesn't give any response in the console'? The backend?

Comment: Hi Riscie, yes. So if there is any data posted on host8080, the console should log 'catching data' (since it triggered the 'app.post' method in my nodejs code). However the console didnt log anything when I trigger the 'http.post' method in my AngularJS code.

Comment: I woul suggest to look into your browsers network tab to check if a request was made or not.

Comment: Thank you Riscie, my question is solved by 'lastWhisper' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http methods in angular are 'cold' methods. the post won't do anything until you subscribe to the returned Observable.

So lets stick to the heroes example:

```
addHero (name: string): Observable<Hero> {
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.post(this.heroesUrl, { name }, options)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

So if you call that `addHero` function somewhere you want to actually post something (lets say a submit button), you can subscribe to the observable. And only this subscription will actually start the post method:

**Calling component (typescript):**

```
public submit():void{
  this.heroService.addHero
  .subscribe(response -> console.log('My response: ' + response));
}
```

**Corresponding html-template**

```
<button (ngSubmit)="submit()"/>
```

If you now click the button, the submit() function will be called and then subscribe to the observable returned by your function containing the http.post().. method. Subscribe takes a closure and provides the Observable content (your server-response in that case).